# Set max zoom level to a decimal value as it is in zoom level in openlayers map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-6

Trying to set the max zoom level from the zoom value set in the view of the ol map using react. When retrieving the zoom value and trying it to set in the max zoom value, it is getting rounded.

```
view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([110, -45]),
        zoom: 8.5,
});

map.getView().setMaxZoom(map.getView().getZoom());
```

For instance, if my zoom is 8.5, after setting this to max zoom, it becomes 9.

Expected : If my zoom is 8.5, then the max zoom also should be 8.5 and not a rounded value.

Comment: `maxZoom` defines how many entries `getResolutions()` returns.  An array always has an integer number of entries.

Comment: I understand that there is no possibility of having a decimal value in maxZoom attribute of the view, right?

Comment: Correct, the minimum resolution will always have an integer zoom value.